# Is there an "elementary irrational number" without a certain digit in its decimal presentation?

Tags: real-analysis, irrational-numbers, elementary-functions

In this question, I define an "elementary irrational number" as an irrational number which is built up of a finite combination of integers, field operations (addition, multiplication, division, and root extractions -- the elementary operations) and exponential and trigonometric functions and their inverses under repeated compositions, as if the definition of [elementary function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunction.html) (I made up the name since I couldn't find it on the Internet). The numbers $\pi=\arccos(-1)$, $\mathrm e=\exp(1)$ and $\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt5}2$ are "elementary irrational numbers", while $1$, $\frac32$ and $1.2121121112\dots$ are not.

It's easy to find either a rational number or an irrational one without a certain digit in its decimal presentation, for example, $1.2121121112\dots$ doesn't contain digit $0$. However, among "elementary irrational numbers", it seems hard to find such number, despite proving there is no such number is not easy either.

I can come up with some possible ways to solve the problem:

- Most constructed numbers aren't "elementary", while there does exists possibility to find one.
- To disprove the existence of such number, we may prove through all the operations to build up the elementary functions that if its arguments are "elementary number(s)" which is/are either rational or contains every kind of digit, then the result satisfies the same property, but it seems to be quite difficult to prove it.
- Or maybe the problem is connected to some existed open problems in mathematics (normal numbers might be an example), then we may be convinced with the difficulty of the problem.

I'd appreciate it if you could give me any advice on the problem.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "is the value at $0$ of an elementary function"? I originally thought it meant that the number in question was $f(0)$ for some elementary function $f$, but that didn't seem to fit with your examples, such as $e = $ exp$(1)$.

Comment: $f(x)=x+1.2121121112\dots$ is an elementary function, is it not?  It contains only elementary operations (*here, addition*) and field elements of $\Bbb R$.  I understand what you intend, but the definition needs more nuance.  Presumably one where the only allowed field elements come from $\Bbb Q$, but that might throw off things like $\text{exp}$ and the like if not careful.

Comment: See [normal numbers](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalNumber.html).  Very little is known...it is widely guessed (with almost no evidence) that algebraic irrationals are normal, which is akin to what you are asking.  But, really, very little is known.

Comment: Can we even prove that $1.2121121112\ldots$ is not elementary irrational?

Comment: @JMoravitz Sorry for that mistake. I've replaced the ambiguous definition with a new one which no longer involves elementary functions, though it does look like the definition of them.